# Contenful content displaying twice in GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, content-management-system, gatsby, contentful, contentful-api

I'm learning gatsby and contentful to build a website but with when I query data from Contentful it displays the same content twice like below. what could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had exactly same problem here for my gatsby+contentful project. I guessed you have two locales set up in Contentful and it will automatically displays all languages you gave to it. To avoid that, you can simply add a filter in your query:

```
query { allContentfulBlogpost(filter: {node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}}) { edges { node { title node_locale } } } }
```

If you see only English show in node_locale that means you success!